# PostgreSQL JSON array value from another column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have `employee` table in postgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Employeename VARCHAR(100));

alter table Employee add column parents JSON;
```

Now, I want to update JSON column with JSON array with a value from the existing column like below.

```
update employee set parents = json_array_elements('[{"name":Employeename, "id":EmployeeID }]')
```

Any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

- `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` function, to generate your json element
- `JSON_BUILD_ARRAY` function, to enclose your json object into an array

```
UPDATE employee 
SET parents = JSON_BUILD_ARRAY(
                  JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('name', Employeename, 
                                    'id'  , EmployeeID   ));
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJm7PNeRBPVVLfEkj9p8Z1/1).

---

If you need to store it as an array, since

Comment: I need this as JSON array not object

Comment: What's the purpose of having an array when the object is only one? What are you aggregating on?

Comment: I will get updates in time to add several other objects

Comment: Nesting json_build_object into json_build_array should do it. Try the demo now.

Answer (score 0):

if `parents` is `json[]`

```
UPDATE employee 
SET parents = array[
                  JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('name', Employeename, 
                                    'id'  , EmployeeID   )]::json[];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35081935/1025379